# Pasting two vectors with combinations of all vectors' elements

Tags: r, r-faq

I have two vectors:

```
vars <- c("SR", "PL")
vis <- c(1,2,3)
```

Based on these vectors I would like to create the following vector:

```
"SR.1"  "SR.2"  "SR.3"  "PL.1"  "PL.2"  "PL.3"
```

With `paste` I have the following result:

```
paste(vars, vis, sep=".")
 [1] "SR.1" "PL.2" "SR.3"
```

How can I create the vector I need?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use this, but there may be a simpler solution :

```
R> apply(expand.grid(vars, vis), 1, paste, collapse=".")
[1] "SR.1" "PL.1" "SR.2" "PL.2" "SR.3" "PL.3"
```

---

`expand.grid` gives back a `data.frame` which when used with `apply`, `apply` will convert it to a `matrix`. This is just unnecessary (and inefficient on large data). `outer` gives a `matrix` and also takes function argument. It'll be much efficient on huge data as well.

Using `outer`:

```
as.vector(outer(vars, vis, paste, sep="."))
# [1] "SR.1" "PL.1" "SR.2" "PL.2" "SR.3" "PL.3"
```

Comment: `expand.grid` returns a table which can be sorted if you want the order to be `SR,SR,PL,PL...` rather than `SR,PL,SR,PL`.

Comment: Considering editing to `do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(vars, vis), sep = "."))` as `paste()` is vectorized.

Answer (score 54):

Another option is to use the `each` argument of `rep`:

```
paste(rep(vars, each = length(vis)), vis, sep = ".")
```

I find this more straightforward than the solutions based on `apply` or `expand.grid`.

Answer (score 22):

Another option using `sprintf` in combination with `expand.grid`:

```
eg <- expand.grid(vis, vars)
sprintf('%s.%s', eg[,2], eg[,1])
```

which gives:

```
[1] "SR.1" "SR.2" "SR.3" "PL.1" "PL.2" "PL.3"
```

Explanation:

- With `expand.grid` you create all combinations of the two vectors.
- `sprintf` pastes the two vectors together according to the specified format (`'%s.%s'`). Each `%s` part of the format is replaced by the elements of the vectors.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution of all suggested!

Answer (score 14):

This old question already has an accepted answer. But as it's being used as dupe target, I believe it's worthwhile to add a `data.table` solution which uses the *cross join* function `CJ()`:

```
library(data.table) 
options(datatable.CJ.names=FALSE) # required with version version 1.12.0+
CJ(vars, vis)[, paste(V1, V2, sep =".")]
#[1] "PL.1" "PL.2" "PL.3" "SR.1" "SR.2" "SR.3"
```

In case the original order is important:

```
CJ(vars, vis, sorted = FALSE)[, paste(V1, V2, sep =".")]
#[1] "SR.1" "SR.2" "SR.3" "PL.1" "PL.2" "PL.3"
```

#### Edit: `CJ()` has changed default behaviour with version 1.12.0

As announced in the [release notes of version 1.12.0](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#notes) (Point 3) the default option `options(datatable.CJ.names=TRUE)` has changed. `CJ()` now auto-names its inputs exactly `as data.table()` does.

So, the code above has to be amended for `data.table` version 1.12.0 and above:

```
library(data.table)   ### version 1.12.0+
CJ(vars, vis)[, paste(vars, vis, sep =".")]
```

and

```
CJ(vars, vis, sorted = FALSE)[, paste(vars, vis, sep =".")]
```

resp.

Answer (score 9):

To maintain the order of the requested strings in the question, you can use these two modifications of both methods:

Change order of vectors and combine in reverse order

```
apply(expand.grid(vis, vars), 1, function(x) paste(x[2], x[1], sep=".")) 
[1] "SR.1" "SR.2" "SR.3" "PL.1" "PL.2" "PL.3"
```

or transpose the matrix before converting to vector:

```
as.vector(t(outer(vars, vis, paste, sep="."))) 
[1] "SR.1" "SR.2" "SR.3" "PL.1" "PL.2" "PL.3"
```

Answer (score 6):

Some other options with `purrr` :

```
library(purrr)
cross(list(vars, vis)) %>% map_chr(paste, sep = ".", collapse = ".")
#[1] "SR.1" "PL.1" "SR.2" "PL.2" "SR.3" "PL.3"
```

We can also use `cross2`

```
cross2(vars, vis) %>%  map_chr(paste, sep = ".", collapse = ".")
#[1] "SR.1" "PL.1" "SR.2" "PL.2" "SR.3" "PL.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

option with dplyr copied from this [link](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html)

```
    fruits <- tibble(
  type   = c("apple", "orange", "apple", "orange", "orange", "orange"),
  year   = c(2010, 2010, 2012, 2010, 2010, 2012),
  size  =  factor(
    c("XS", "S",  "M", "S", "S", "M"),
    levels = c("XS", "S", "M", "L")
  ),
  weights = rnorm(6, as.numeric(size) + 2)
)
```

All possible combinations, i.e. all are defined, but not necessarily present in the data

```
fruits %>% expand(type)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   type  
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 apple 
#> 2 orange
fruits %>% expand(type, size)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   type   size 
#>   <chr>  <fct>
#> 1 apple  XS   
#> 2 apple  S    
#> 3 apple  M    
#> 4 apple  L    
#> 5 orange XS   
#> 6 orange S    
#> 7 orange M    
#> 8 orange L    
b<-fruits %>% expand(type, size, year)
#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#>    type   size   year
#>    <chr>  <fct> <dbl>
#>  1 apple  XS     2010
#>  2 apple  XS     2012
#>  3 apple  S      2010
#>  4 apple  S      2012
#>  5 apple  M      2010
#>  6 apple  M      2012
#>  7 apple  L      2010
#>  8 apple  L      2012
#>  9 orange XS     2010
#> 10 orange XS     2012
#> 11 orange S      2010
#> 12 orange S      2012
#> 13 orange M      2010
#> 14 orange M      2012
#> 15 orange L      2010
#> 16 orange L      2012
```

Then a simple paste

```
b <- fruits %>% expand(type, size, year) %>% 
     mutate(., pasted=paste(type, size, year, sep="."))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another option using base `R`

```
vars <- c("SR", "PL"); vis <- c(1,2,3)

c(sapply(vars, \(x) paste(x, vis, sep = ".")))
[1] "SR.1" "SR.2" "SR.3" "PL.1" "PL.2" "PL.3"
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution will just be

```
paste0(vars,".", vis)
[1] "SR.1" "PL.2" "SR.3"
```