# How to cross-paste all combinations of two vectors (each-to-each)?

Tags: r

I need to paste all combinations of elements from two character vectors, "each" to "each": instead of

```
> paste0(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"))
[1] "ac" "bd"
```

I want to get

```
[1] "ac" "ad" "bc" "bd"
```

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is likely trivial, but I can't find the function `paste0`.  I'm guessing `paste0 <- function(...){paste(..., sep="")}`, is that right?

Comment: `paste0` was added in R 2.15.0 and it is a (slightly) faster version of paste w/ the default separator as the empty string.

Comment: @AdamHyland O wow, I totally missed that, thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also do:

```
outer(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"), FUN = "paste0")[1:4]
[1] "ac" "bc" "ad" "bd"
```

Both `do.call` and `outer` are valuable functions to play with. :)

Alternately, we can assign

```
x <- outer(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"), FUN = "paste0")
dim(x) <- NULL
x
[1] "ac" "bc" "ad" "bd"
```

Without knowing the length.

More edits!

```
x <- outer(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"), FUN = "paste0")
y <- t(x)
dim(y) <- NULL
y
[1] "ac" "ad" "bc" "bd"
```

Gets you the desired order, too.

Comment: Is there a way to paste more than two strings?

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
x <- c("a", "b")
y <- c("c", "d")

do.call(paste0, expand.grid(x, y))
# [1] "ac" "bc" "ad" "bd"
```

It is likely to be slower than `outer` when `x` and `y` are long, but on the other hand it allows the following generalisation:

```
z <- c("e", "f")

do.call(paste0, expand.grid(x, y, z))
# [1] "ace" "bce" "ade" "bde" "acf" "bcf" "adf" "bdf"
```

Comment: You can write a recursive wrapper to `outer` which will do that for an arbitrary number of inputs. It's WAAAY uglier than `expand.grid` (see [here](https://gist.github.com/Protonk/5799974) for a first cut) but it's faster. However as I note, you can run your snippet 200,000 times in ~ 1/20th of a second, so it's probably ok. :)

Comment: @Julius, your answer was very handy (+1). However, is there a way to preserve order -- say when naming columns etc.? For the e.g. above, if the required order is `"ac" "ad" "bc" "bd"`? In my case, I have words that need to be pasted together in a particular order (to retaining meaning). Thanks!

Comment: @rmk, an optimal way to do that would be to notice that `expand.grid` uses a reverse ordering in a sense compared to what you need, thus `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(y, x)[2:1])` should work. Similarly e.g. `expand.grid(z, y, x)[3:1]`.

Answer (score 10):

Another (less generally useful) incantation:

```
levels(interaction(x,y,sep=""))
# [1] "ac" "bc" "ad" "bd"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be used.

```
comb <- function(x,y) 
         {
          x1 <- rep(x, each=length(y))
          y1 <- rep(y, times=length(x))
          paste0(x1,y1)
         }
comb(2:4, 5:7)
```