# R language cross-product combination of two string arrays

Tags: arrays, r, combinations

suppose I have two arrays a and b:

```
a=seq(2013,2015)
b=c('-03-31','-06-30')
```

I would like to combine each element in a with each in b. The result should be an array which looks like:

```
"2013-03-31" "2013-06-30" "2014-03-31" "2014-06-30" "2015-03-31" "2015-06-30"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't understand why this post is voted -3. Anyone who voted can explain? The answer for akrun is what I am looking for, thanks akrun.

Comment: For example If I google a keyword "r every combination of two vectors", I get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements  which is basically what you asked.

Comment: still seems bad form to downvote without a comment as to why

Comment: @akrun, I think you might be right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try

```
c(outer(a, b, FUN=paste0))
#[1] "2013-03-31" "2014-03-31" "2015-03-31" "2013-06-30" "2014-06-30"
#[6] "2015-06-30"
```

Or

```
do.call(paste0,expand.grid(a,b))
```

Or

```
sprintf('%s%s', rep(a, length(b)), rep(b, length(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

akrun's examples work well if you want a character vector as your result, but they do not make it easy to work with each side of the pair.

This function will give you a list containing the cross-product of two sets:

```
cross <- function(x, y = x) {

    result <- list()

    for (a in unique(x)) {

        for (b in unique(y)) {

            result <- append(result, list(list(left = a, right = b)))
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Example:

```
cross(c(1, 2, 3), c("a", "b", "c"))
```