# Correct way to concatenate lists of strings in R

Tags: r, string

What is the *idiomatic* way to do the following string concatenation in R?

Given two vectors of strings, such as the following,

```
titles <- c("A", "B")
sub.titles <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

I want to produce the vector

```
full.titles <- c("A_x", "A_y", "A_z", "B_x", "B_y", "B_z")
```

Obviously, this could be done with two for-loops. However, I would like to know what an “idiomatic” (i.e., elegant and natural) solution would be in R.

In Python, an idiomatic solution might look like this:

```
titles = ['A', 'B']
subtitles = ['x', 'y', 'z']
full_titles = ['_'.join([title, subtitle])
               for title in titles for subtitle in subtitles]
```

Does R allow for a similar degree of expressiveness?

**Remark**

The consensus among the solutions proposed thus far is that the idiomatic way to do this in R is, basically,

```
full.titles <- c(t(outer(titles, sub.titles, paste, sep = "_")))
```

Interestingly, this has an (almost) literal translation in Python:

```
full_titles = map('_'.join, product(titles, subtitles))
```

where `product` is the cartesian-product function from the itertools module. However, in Python, such a use of `map` is considered more convoluted—that is, *less* expressive—than the equivalent use of list comprehension, as above.

Comment: @brittenb that does not produce the vector as required in the question.

Comment: @zacdav Yeah, I'm looking at the output now and am confused as to why it's not producing the expected output. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: Somewhat direct translation: mapply(function(x,y) sprintf("%s_%s", x, y), rep(titles, each=length(subtitles)), subtitles)

Comment: R is more "colorful" than Python in this example...wonder how many diff ways everyone can think of...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements

Comment: for the order, just add sort.

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: Or just transpose any of the solutions proposed below. :)

Comment: @chinsoon12: I would say R is more “convoluted“ than Python. ;) (But also more concise, when it comes to working with tabular data.) I updated the question with a remark showing how to be “colorful” (but not necessarily more readable nor more efficient) in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this, either using the 'outer()' function to define your function as the matrix product of two vectors, along the lines of:

`outer(titles, sub.titles, paste, sep='_')`

and then wrangling it from a matrix into a vector, or converting your input to dataframe, using `expand.grid()`

`do.call(paste, expand.grid(titles, sub.titles, sep='_', stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`

Comment: You can probably wrap it into `c` as in `c(outer(titles, sub.titles, paste, sep='_'))`

Comment: Elegant. This almost produces the correct output. Unfortunately, the resulting components are in the wrong order. (I've updated the question to clarify this.) A transpose fixes this: `c(t(outer(...)))`

Answer (score 3):

Using `do.call` combined with `paste` and `expand.grid`

```
sort(do.call(paste, c(sep='_', expand.grid(titles, sub.titles))))
#[1] "A_x" "A_y" "A_z" "B_x" "B_y" "B_z"
```

Or using `tidyr::unite` combined with `expand.grid`

```
unite(expand.grid(titles, sub.titles), Res, everything()) %>% .$Res
```

Comment: sure it's base R ;) But I tend use Curry quite a lot. Also looking for an elegant one liner using `tidyr`, but `unite_(expand.grid(titles, sub.titles), everything())` does not seem to work

Comment: you can post it as an answer since you solved my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
apply(expand.grid(titles, sub.titles), 1, paste, collapse = "_")
```

`expand.grid` creates a matrix of combinations between `titles` and `sub.titles`.
`apply` goes down the matrix of combinations and pastes them together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

`unlist(lapply(1:length(titles), function(x){paste(titles[x], sub.titles, sep="_")}))`

Answer (score 1):

This code also works: `as.vector(outer(titles, subtitles, FUN=paste, sep="_"))`

`outer` essentially performs a function element-wise to each element from each vector. So it'll take each element from `titles` and perform a function with each element from `subtitles`. The default function is multiplication, but we change that default by passing a new argument to the `FUN` parameter. Arguments that are used in our new function are appended after a comma. So we're telling R to take the first element from `titles` and paste it together with each element from `subtitles` and separate the two elements with a "_". Then do it again with the second element from `titles`.

Answer (score 1):

```
full.titles  <-  paste0(expand.grid(titles,sub.titles)$Var1,'_',
expand.grid(titles,sub.titles)$Var2)
>full.titles
[1] "A_x" "B_x" "A_y" "B_y" "A_z" "B_z"
```