# Text Matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

These are my two text matrices:

```
A <- matrix(c("AIP-A","CSV-A"), ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c("AIP-B","CSV-B"), ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
```

I am trying to get the multiplication of these matrices and the output should look like this:

```
AIP-A,AIP-B
AIP-A,CSV-B
CSV-A,AIP-B
CSV-A,CSV-B
```

A*B does not work because it is looking for numeric inputs. Maybe the same result can be achieved by some other technique. 
I am ok with 4x2 output matrix, a 4x1 matrix ,a character vector, data.frame and data.table

Comment: @Jota absolutely. I did not know of this outer function. Kindly post it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pasting two vectors with combinations of all vectors' elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements)

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you delete the repeated thank you comments.  While appreciated, these are generally frowned upon on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(A[,1], B[,1])[, paste(V1, V2, sep=", ")]
#[1] "AIP-A, AIP-B" "AIP-A, CSV-B" "CSV-A, AIP-B" "CSV-A, CSV-B"
```

Wrap it with `matrix` to create a single column `matrix`

```
 matrix(CJ(A[,1], B[,1])[, paste(V1, V2, sep=", ")])
 #   [,1]          
 #[1,] "AIP-A, AIP-B"
 #[2,] "AIP-A, CSV-B"
 #[3,] "CSV-A, AIP-B"
 #[4,] "CSV-A, CSV-B"
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 data_frame(A=A[,1], B=B[,1]) %>% 
         complete(A,B) %>% 
          unite(AB, A,B)
 #          AB
 #        <chr>
 #1 AIP-A_AIP-B
 #2 AIP-A_CSV-B
 #3 CSV-A_AIP-B
 #4 CSV-A_CSV-B
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `outer` for outer product of arrays with `paste` to get your desired  output:

```
c(outer(A, B, paste, sep = ","))
# [1] "AIP-A,AIP-B" "CSV-A,AIP-B" "AIP-A,CSV-B" "CSV-A,CSV-B"
```

or

```
matrix(outer(A, B, paste, sep = ","), ncol = 1)
#     [,1]         
#[1,] "AIP-A,AIP-B"
#[2,] "CSV-A,AIP-B"
#[3,] "AIP-A,CSV-B"
#[4,] "CSV-A,CSV-B"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your definition of "multiplication" but using `cbind` and `rep` you get this:

```
> cbind(rep(A,each=nrow(B)),rep(B,nrow(A)))
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "AIP-A" "AIP-B"
[2,] "AIP-A" "CSV-B"
[3,] "CSV-A" "AIP-B"
[4,] "CSV-A" "CSV-B"
```

Answer (score 2):

This method uses `expand.grid` with `Reduce` and `paste`:

```
Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=","), expand.grid(A,B))
[1] "AIP-A,AIP-B" "CSV-A,AIP-B" "AIP-A,CSV-B" "CSV-A,CSV-B"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want a 4x2 output matrix, try `expand.grid`.  No packages are used.

```
as.matrix(expand.grid(B = B, A = A)[2:1])
```

giving:

```
     A       B      
[1,] "AIP-A" "AIP-B"
[2,] "AIP-A" "CSV-B"
[3,] "CSV-A" "AIP-B"
[4,] "CSV-A" "CSV-B"
```

If the order, whether it is a matrix and the headings are unimportant then  `expand.grid(A, B)` may be sufficient.