# Combine 2 lists, combinations between 2 lists but not within a list

Tags: r, list

I have

```
list1 <- c("A","B","C")
```

and

```
list2 <- c(1,2,3)
```

And I want a joined list:

```
list3 = c("A_1", "B_2", "C_3").
```

I've looked everywhere but cannot find the answer.
I've tried mapply, combn, permn... All did not work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would assume that there are quotes i.e. `c("A", "B", "C")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `paste`.  The input datasets are `vector`s

```
v1 <- paste(list1, list2, sep = "_")
dput(v1)
#c("A_1", "B_2", "C_3")
```

But, if they are `list` elements and wanted a `vector` as output

```
paste(unlist(list1), unlist(list2), sep = "_")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem. And thanks for editing my question too.

Comment: Just another question, if I may. How about
`list3 <- c("A_1","A_2","A_3", "B_1","B_2","B_3","C_1","C_2","C_3")`

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements. Thanks!!

Comment: @TVV I hope you don't have any difficulty