# call a value among two values in one cell in a matrix

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix, igraph

There are two vectors `x: 1 3 5 7` & `y: 2 4 6 8`. I used the function [outer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements) to build a `matrix(4*4)` from all possible combinations between the elements in both vectors like:

```
x<-c(1,3,5,7)
y<-c(2,4,6,8)
comb<-outer(x,y, paste, sep=".")
> comb
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
[1,] "1.2" "1.4" "1.6" "1.8"
[2,] "3.2" "3.4" "3.6" "3.8"
[3,] "5.2" "5.4" "5.6" "5.8"
[4,] "7.2" "7.4" "7.6" "7.8"
```

I don't now if it is possible to index one element in a cell, for example if there is a way to call only the `element 2` from first cell `comb[1,1]`
Is there something like `comb[[1,1]][2]=2` "I know it is not working"

And if this is not possible in this way, is there another way construct a matrix from the combinations and to be able after that to call and index each element alone??

By the way: I work on graphs and vectors of vertices so if there are other functions like this one for graphs please direct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `outer` works fine for what you need. To get the second element from your matrix use substr  like this:

```
substr(comb[1,1],3,3)
```

note that I selected the 3 because it is the 3 element of the character that you need.

you can also use `strsplit` if there numbers with more than 1 digit in your matrix

```
unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]
```

**EDIT**

If you change the matrix to a vector it would be something like this

```
vector_comb = c(comb)
sapply(1:length(vector_comb), function(x) unlist(strsplit(comb[x], ".", fixed = T))[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and answer but for a huge data how could I know what is the order of the character I am trying to call from the cell especially inside a loop?! I think it will not be efficient solution!! isn't it? are there other other solutions?

Comment: @user8003788 if each element of your matrix is past with a dot in the middle the second option works perfect, because it will split each element in the 2 numbers you paste and selected the second one so you know exactly what you are extracting. The substr wouldn't work that well

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks but I also I want to ask if I decided to convert the matrix into a vector again then is it possible to call each element alone in the cell of the vector?

Comment: @user8003788 if you do something as.numeric(comb) it would become a vector and then you have to do change the way you call each element, like comb[1]

Comment: Thanks, in this way it will read the whole cell not each element alone in the cell

Comment: I added an example that of how you would do it in a vector

Comment: Thanks a lot..it is great

Comment: when using this function (unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]) and applying it on vertices in graphs how it is possible to keep the vertex name and don't mix it by the vertex number? I tried something like *names(unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]) and like *V(g)$names(unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]) but it didn't work!! is there another way

Comment: not sure, if you give me a sample of the data i will be happy to help

Comment: I will update the question and add another part for graph vertices

Comment: its better if you create an other question, its SO policy that its one question per thread

Comment: Ok I will do and I will add a link to this question, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ? By using [`Vectorize`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html)

```
comb<-outer(x,y, Vectorize( function(a,b) c( as.list(a), as.list(b) ),SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
comb
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
[2,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
[3,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
[4,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
comb[[1,1]][2]
[[1]]
[1] 2

comb[[1,1]][1]
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

Update :

```
unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1],'.',fixed = T))[1]
[1] "1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but is it possible to show this matrix by filled by the elements themselves? i.e the form like my matrix above but to be able to use your index?

Comment: @user8003788 base on you description , you need a list in every cell , so that is join type , which I usually do not recommend . And the view of the list item come with the problem you just mention above (can not show on view table )

Comment: @Wen whats the differences between fixed = 2  and fixed = T?

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade it is my bad , we should using fixed =TRUE

Comment: Ok, I understand you.. Excuse for this and if I decided to convert the matrix into a vector again then is it possible to call each element alone in the cell of the vector?

Comment: @user8003788 if you chose `unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1],'.',fixed = T))[1]` you do not need , it is base on `comb<-outer(x,y, paste, sep=".")`

Comment: @user8003788 yw~ happy coding

Comment: @Wen, if I applied this function (unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]) on graph vertices then how it is possible to keep the vertex name and don't mix it by the vertex number? I applied this one *names(unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]) and this one *V(g)$names(unlist(strsplit(comb[1,1], ".", fixed = T))[2]) and I failed, is there something else?