# How to append 60 time values to a list of 4 million concatenated longitude and latitude values?

Tags: r, vector, concatenation, vectorization, large-data

I am trying to make a vector that is 244,466,460 long that is the longitude, latitude and time as one value e.g., -1556788_-2323088_558322882.

I have extracted the longitude and latitudes from my NetCDF file and concatenated them into a variable concatLonLat, large character, 4,074,441 elements, e.g. -1556788_-2323088

How do I take the 4 million lonLat values and add the time so that the data is like this:

[1,] -1556788_-2323088_558322882 (first time added to the first row)

...

[4074441,] -1608563_-2275088_558322882 (the first time is added to the 4 millionth and something row)

[4074442,] -1556788_-2323088_559705304 (the second time is added to the next 4 million and something rows etc)

Why am I doing this?
I asked a previous question about normalised difference water index (NDWI) and was told to vectorise - which I did successfully.

But, if I use the complete Red Green BLue vectors to form a matrix to run RGB2Lab() I run out of memory.
I can reduce my vectors by 80% by taking out all the open water values.
And then not run out of memory.

But then I can't match up the long, lat and time to the vectors or RGB and Lab matrices.
Unless there is some function that I am missing that will do this for me.
So if I make a vector of long lat and time that matches my other vectors and then take out the same 80% then the vectors will all match up right?

And I can then run the RGB2Lab function with lon lat and time.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143700/pasting-two-vectors-with-combinations-of-all-vectors-elements/16143862), you can use:

```
as.vector(outer(coords, times, paste, sep="_"))
```

with `coords` being the vector of lon/lat values, and `times` the vector of time values.

Example:

```
x <- c("test", "test2", "test3")
y <- 1:2

as.vector(outer(x, y, paste, sep = "_"))
[1] "test_1"  "test2_1" "test3_1" "test_2"  "test2_2" "test3_2"
```

Comment: Thanks. The code didn't throw up an error. The script has been running for 45 minutes and is still not complete. How long should it take?

Comment: the code doesn't appear to work. after just over an hour waiting for the code to complete execution R is not responding. I'll try break it ingdown and do a for loop to cycle through the coords and time

Comment: Does it work for a small subset? Your data is extremely large, and the result may not fit in your memory.

Comment: yes. This code:
lonLatSeconds_vec_1to3 <- as.vector(outer(concatLonLat,time_1to3,paste,sep="_")). So... if I cycle through and create vectors that are shorter. Once I have the whole set of vectors, will R handle appending the vectors in less memory than trying to do the 1 to 60 times at once using outer?

Comment: Yes. I am using 18 time sections and then writing the vector to a file to later join together with other vectors.